# How to avoid showing default keyboard android

Tags: android

I have an default expanded search widget in activity. when activity launches and also when search widget cross(x) is pressed, it show keyboard. I want to avoid showing keyboard until user tap on field.

I tried

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

But no luck.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't know the exact method, but what's happening is that your text box is getting focus by default.  This usually happens when it's the first (or only) editable item on the screen.  You need to clear that default so it won't automatically activate the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can focus your main layout, then the keyboard will not show.
like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.layout).requestFocus();
```

If not work, then you can close the keyboard automatically, like this:

```
View v = getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

}

And i think you can also disable the "focusable" in your widget on the xml.